# Google's RuntimeConfig API responds with 'Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network'

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, gcloud, runtime-configuration

Since today (november 20 2018) we get error responses from Google's RuntimeConfig API:

`Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it&#39;s really you sending the requests, and not a robot...`

([check this link for complete HTML error](https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/blabla))

We retrieve variables from Google's RuntimeConfig using the API in our code. We do quite a few request, but not more than before:

A developer starts his server locally, which retrieves all the needed variables (+- 30 everytime you start).

Requesting RuntimeConfig variables via GCloud results in the same HTML error:
`gcloud beta runtime-config configs variables get-value databaseHost --config-name database --project=your-test-environment`

Other `gcloud` api requests work (projects describe, gsutil, etc).

How can I verify if I violated any terms? I can only find a usage limit in GCloud Console of 6000 calls per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the exact same issue on November 20th when a large amount of our preemptibles were reallocated at the same time.

Our startup-scripts make use of the `gcloud beta runtime-config...`-commands and they all responded with 503.
These commands responded correctly again after a few hours.

We have had a support-ticket with Google and there was a problem with their internal quota mechanisms at the time which since is fixed so the issue is resolved.

Comment: This was the issue for me aswell. We created a package which caches the runtime config on local filesystem, to prevent issues like these in the future. (private package unfortunatly)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the quotas for Runtime Configurator and how much of those you are using in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) under [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas). In the Quotas section you can filter on Service = Cloud Runtime Configuration API and you should see all the quotas and how close to those you are for this API. There are 4 quotas that may affect you ([docs here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/quotas)):

- 1200 Queries Per Minute (QPM) for delete, create, and update requests
- 600 QPM for watch requests
- 6000 QPM for get and list requests.
- 4MB of data per project, which consists of all data written to the Runtime Configurator service and accompanying metadata.

[image]